# How to catch an error with Application.WorksheetFunction.Match and handle it?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I'm using the `Application.match` function to look for the column number of the column heading I'm looking for. I want a customized pop up MsgBox if none of the headings are a match.

Before it gets to the IfError statement, Excel stops my program and shows a MsgBox that says there was no match

```
col_num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("wanted name", theDataWS.Rows(1), 0)

If IsError(col_num) Then 
    MsgBox "Please rename your column name to 'wanted name'"
End If
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.

---

- `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` will throw a run-time error if there is no match. You could trap and handle it with an `On Error...` statement if you wanted, or perhaps better in this case, use `Application.Match`.
- `Application.Match` will not throw a run-time error; instead, the variable `col_num` will hold the error value (in this case *Error 2042* corresponding to `#N/A`). Thus you can then test `IsError(col_num)`.*

---

*Note that in this case `col_num` should be a `Variant` (declared either implicitly with `Dim col_num` or explicitly with `Dim col_num As Variant`).

Comment: You might mention that *col_num* needs to be a variant in order to catch the error.

Comment: @user11026105 yeah, I had in my wording at some point but didn't include it for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

To use `Application.WorhsheetFunction.Match` that might not find a match, you need to use an Error Handler.

Something like

```
On Error Resume Next
col_num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("wanted name", theDataWS.Rows(1), 0)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error Goto 0 ' restore error handling as soon as possible
    MsgBox "Please rename your column name to 'wanted name'"
Else
    On Error Goto 0
    ' non-error code
End If
```

Or use `Application.Match` as others have answered